# Angular JS - block in method calling $http.get until data is returned

Tags: angularjs, validation, drag-and-drop, typescript

I understand that AngularJS forces you to be asynchronous everywhere, but I am running into an issue with drag and drop validation that:

- Requires a $scope method to return a boolean;
- That boolean value is the result of a call to a REST endpoint (ASP.NET WebAPI)

The drag and drop implementation I'm using is [this one](http://www.directiv.es/Angular-DragDrop).

In short, when the user starts to drag an item, a method is called to validate whether or not the drag is valid.

Within this validation method, I need to make a call to a REST endpoint that will execute some logic to determine of the drag source is able to be dropped on the drag target.

That $http.get is asynchronous is stopping me from being able to return the result of the get.

In my view I have the drag/drop configured as such:

```
<table class="grid" style="margin-left: 15px" ui-on-drop="onDrop($event,$data,someId)" drop-validate="validateDrop($data, someId)">
<!-- rows in here -->
</table>
```

In the controller, I have the method:

```
$scope.validateDrop = (data, someId) => {
    var res = $http.get('/some/url/that/returns/bool');
    //
    // how to return the result of the GET, and NOT a promise?
    //
    return true; //should return value of the GET
};
```

Things I have considered:

- There can be a significant number of draggable items that can have multiple drop targets.  I don't think it's viable to pull a "validation matrix" on load.
- I understand that blocking is not the done thing, but this may be a valid case

Is there a way to either

- Restructure the validation so that it could support the async call (not sure on this, and I'd like to avoid modifying the drag and drop library)
- Force the get to be synchronous, or somehow block until the result is known.

Comment: Are the drag and droppable items created on the fly or predefined?

Comment: If they are predefined you could just add an array of valid targets to each item when they are fetched initially, and in that way avoid unnecessary api calls.

Comment: You first need to consider the user experience that you are after. Imagine that $http call takes 10 seconds - what is the user experience? Does the drop happen, and then bounces back on error? Is there another experience? This most likely won't fit under normal scenarios envisioned for drop validation, and you may need to implement higher-level validation constructs to support what you are building. Blocking is never the valid case with UI

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind to promises so you need to work around the issue. Perhaps at drag-start create unique ID and store the drag information / lookup result in a hash. Then bind to that result which will be updated when the get promise is completed.